# Matlab division, cannot get back the answer

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

```
    H = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8; 9 10; 11 12; 13 14; 15 16];
    X = [7; 9];
    Y = H*X;
    H1 = Y/X;
```

This is my code. As you can see, I was trying to get back the H values. However, it gave me something else. I have tried to use inv() but this is not possible because X is not a square matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a value of rank 2 back by dividing a value of rank 1.  The system is underconstrained.

Both `mrdivide` and `pinv` (for pseudo-inverse) can be used to get *a* solution to the system.  Because there are multiple solutions, it wouldn't necessary be the one you started with.  Instead you'll get a "simplest" solution, either in the sense of lowest cardinality or lowest 2-norm, depending on whether you use `mrdivide` or `pinv`.

Here, the `pinv` documentation page probably explains it more precisely than I can.  Just note it is discussing `X\Y` instead of `Y/X`:

> If A has more rows than columns and is not of full rank, then the overdetermined least squares problem
>
> ```
> minimize norm(A*x-b)
> ```
>
> does not have a unique solution. Two of the infinitely many solutions are
>
> ```
> x = pinv(A)*b
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> y = A\b
> ```
>
> These two are distinguished by the facts that `norm(x)` is smaller than the norm of any other solution and that `y` has the fewest possible nonzero components.